# Web Page of Typo3 templates

Tags: templates, typo3

I would like to know if someone can help me to find one template for typo3. The requirements that i need for this template are:

- Responsive
- Multilanguage
- Custom
- SEO

I'm looking for TYPO3 template libraries. They don't need to be free. I'm looking for real Typo3 templates, ready to import into a vanilla Typo3 installation.

The reason I'm asking is that we have a customer and we'd like to give them a number of templates to choose from.

I need something like this page http://www.t3-template.de/typo3-template-kaufen.

Thanks in advance.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for somthing like this combination of TYPO3 extensions (TYPO3 6.2 or newer):
First of all you need *themes* (optional: *gridelements, themes_gridelements*)

install some themes like: *theme_bootstrap, theme_foundation, theme_bootstrap_mosaic*...

and switch the installed themes in the frontend with this
*themes_showcase*

Some dependencies (*dyncss* and so on) are solved automatically but dont forget *t3jquery* for all features.

Have a look here for more details:
https://github.com/typo3-themes